# beginner question regarding multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, json, azure, powershell, nested

So I have this array of informations I gather from my azure subscription that is converted from json:

```
$Request += (((az consumption usage list --subscription $subscriptionID --start-date $CycleStart --end-date $CycleEnd) 2> $null | ConvertFrom-Json) | select subscriptionname, instanceName, usageStart, usageEnd, pretaxCost, tags )
```

That produce an array that looks ok :

```
$Request 

subscriptionName : Sub1
instanceName : VM1
usageStart : 2020-01-27T00:00:00Z
usageEnd : 2020-01-27T23:59:59Z
pretaxCost : 3.194
tags : @{Classification=ABC, Zone=123, Field=qaz, Org=CAL, Owner=Bob@dev}

subscriptionName : Sub1
instanceName : VM2
usageStart : 2020-01-27T00:00:00Z
usageEnd : 2020-01-27T23:59:59Z
pretaxCost : 2.1
tags : @{Classification=zzz, Zone=123, Field=qaz, Org=NZ, Owner=John@prod}
```

But as you see, the field "tags" looks merged between @{xxxx}. What I would like to acheive and couldn't after hours of trial&error (!) is something like that :

```
subscriptionName : Sub1
instanceName : VM1
usageStart : 2020-01-27T00:00:00Z
usageEnd : 2020-01-27T23:59:59Z
pretaxCost : 3.194
Classification : ABC
Zone : 123
Field : qaz
Org : CAL
Owner : Bob@dev

subscriptionName : Sub1
instanceName : VM2
usageStart : 2020-01-27T00:00:00Z
usageEnd : 2020-01-27T23:59:59Z
pretaxCost : 2.1
Classification : ABC
Zone : 222
Field : BIZ
Org : NZ
Owner : John@dev
```

But... the field nested under "tags" can change over the time so I can't hardcode something that will look for "Classification", "Zone", "Field", etc...)

Can anyone help me with this one ? :)

I came accross that script thinking it could help but wasn't able to make it work..
https://github.com/solidstate888/JSON-ToCSV

Comment: ConvertFrom-Json has a [-Depth parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)

Comment: yes but by default the depth is at 1024 so that should work.. but I think ConvertFrom-Json cant correctly parse the field "tags" because that doesn't look like properly formed json ...

Comment: @frank See  my answer for working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the `tags` field, I believe it is a hash table.

You verify this by examining the type of the tags property in one of your array elements:

```
$Request[0].tags | Get-Member
```

Should show:

[image]

So, for each hash table entry, all you have to do is output each hash table key (which is the field name) and its hash table value (which the field value)

Please note that the block of code above the comment `#code to output the input array` is there only to create a two-row array that simulates what I see in your question, The code that I believe you need (the code to output the array contents) is below the comment `#code to output the input array`. In particular, see the loop `foreach($tag in $object.tags.keys)`. This loop outputs whatever collection of key+value pairs is present in the `tags` field (the hash table) of the input array. This deals with the statement in your question:

> But... the field nested under "tags" can change over the time

Note that my simulated objects have two different sets of key+value pairs in the tags hash table and my code deals with outputting the different content.

```
cls

#code to create simulated array that looks like the content of your question
#In your program, I assume that this array is created by using ConvertFrom-Json 
$Request = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$field = [ordered]@{}

$field.subscriptionName  = 'Sub1'
$field.instanceName = 'VM1'
$field.usageStart  = Get-Date -Date '2020-01-27T00:00:00Z'
$field.usageEnd = Get-Date -Date '2020-01-27T23:59:59Z'
$field.pretaxCost = 3.194
$field.tags = @{Classification='ABC'; Zone=123; Field='qaz'; Org='CAL'; Owner='Bob@dev'}
$Request.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $field)) | out-null

$field.subscriptionName  = 'Sub1'
$field.instanceName = 'VM2'
$field.usageStart  = Get-Date -Date '2020-01-27T00:00:00Z'
$field.usageEnd = Get-Date -Date '2020-01-27T23:59:59Z'
$field.pretaxCost = 2.1
#Note that this tags hash table has content that is different when compared to the tags hash table in the first element of the array above
$field.tags = @{Foo1='foo1'; Foo2="Foo2"; Field='qaz'; Foo3=6677}
$Request.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $field)) | out-null

#code to output the input array

foreach ($fieldItem in $Request)
{
    write-host ("subscriptionName={0}" -f $fieldItem.subscriptionName)
    write-host ("instanceName={0}" -f $fieldItem.instanceName)
    write-host ("usageStart={0}" -f $fieldItem.usageStart)
    write-host ("usageEnd={0}" -f $fieldItem.usageEnd)
    write-host ("pretaxCost={0}" -f $fieldItem.pretaxCost)

    foreach($tag in $fieldItem.tags.keys)
    {
        write-host ("{0}={1}" -f $tag, $fieldItem.tags.$tag)
    }

    write-host
}
```

**Output**

[image]